# Unable to generate meanjs using yeoman generator

Tags: node.js, msbuild

I am trying to generate Meanjs with yo meanjs command,
. Installed the generator generator-meanjs. 
But when I tried to install meanjs I am getting below error. Please suggest on what to do.

```
    Unhandled rejection Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "cd mean && npm install"

    npm WARN engine karma@0.12.37: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","npm":"3.3.3"})

    npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","npm":"3.3.3"})

    npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported

    npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported

    npm WARN prefer global jshint@2.8.0 should be installed with -g

    npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.0.3 should be installed with -g

    npm WARN prefer global nodemon@1.3.8 should be installed with -g
    gyp ERR! build error

    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

            gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)





            gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601

             gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"


            gyp ERR! cwd C:\MEANProject\mean\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\bu fferutil
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON mean@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
    npm ERR! node v4.1.1
    npm ERR! npm  v3.3.3
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    npm ERR! bufferutil@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@1.1.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bufferutil package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls bufferutil
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     C:\MEANProject\mean\npm-debug.log

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

below is the setup:

```
$ node -v
 v4.1.1
$ npm --v
2.14.3
$ yo --version
1.4.8
```

Please Suggest..

Comment: what's the command you used?

Comment: @ Michelem $ yo meanjs

Answer (score 1):

Check it out 
https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/issues/117

Hope It will help!

Try this thing with lower version of Node (0.12.7)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have node 4.1.1 installed.
The Yeoman generator does not support that version of Node as yet, as it did not support io.js.

If you still want to use meanjs you will have to downgrade your version of node to 0.12.x

Comment: It looks like now meanjs does support node 4.x